# Reactjs: how to sort columns if column name is dynamic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting

I know that to sort a column we use
`sorter: (a, b) => a.monthName - b.monthName`
but in my case, my column name (i.e. monthName) is not hardcoded but is generated dynamically as I load the component. So for this my row object looks like:

```
   November: xyz,
   December: xyz,
   January: xyz,
   forecasted: xyz
```

I'm adding Nov, Dec, Jan i.e. the names of the months dynamically in the state via

```
const newColumn = {
        title: monthName,
        dataIndex: monthName,
        key: monthName,
        sorter: (a, b) => a.monthName - b.monthName,
        render(text,record){}
       }
```

I can't hardcode the month names as I need last 3 months' names.
Is there a way I can pass column name to this sort function?
How can I sort the columns in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You could save the column's name into a variable (or in this case state) and address the variable when sorting.

Example:

```js
var columnName = 'monthName';

(a, b) => a[columnName] - b[columnName];
```

Comment: I'm a little confused. Where do I set this var columnName? Because we'll have 3 column names then. I need sort function to identify which column is this function being called for

Comment: If I understand you and the code stated in the initial question right then you could use `monthName` that you are also using for `title` and `key`. So simply replace `columnName` with `monthName` in my example. So basically you change your dot notation with bracket notation, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#bracket_notation